# Read file with ascii encoding

Tags: node.js

file:

```
聵
```

script:

```
require("fs").readFile ("file", "ascii", function (e, d){
    console.log(d==="聵") //true
})
```

How is this possible? `聵` is not an ascii character, is encoded with 3 bytes, 0xE881B5. What I expect is to get `è\u0081µ` because ascii characters are encoded with a single byte. If I read using "binary" encoding it prints true, what I expect with ascii encoding...

```
require("fs").readFile ("file", "binary", function (e, d){
    console.log(d === "è\u0081µ") //true
})
```

Is this result an intentional feature? If ascii encoding returns the same result as utf8 encoding then why is "ascii" a possible parameter?

EDIT:

This is the content (opened with HxD program):

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  E8 81 B5                                         è.µ
```

and:

```
require("fs").readFile ("file", function (e, d){
    console.log (d.toString ("ascii") === "聵") //true
    console.log (d.toString ("utf8") === "聵") //true
    console.log (d.toString ("binary") === "è\u0081µ") //true
    console.log (d) //<Buffer e8 81 b5>
})
```

The issue is submitted to the devs: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4413

Comment: For clarity, also add a) hex dump of file, b) length of `d` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug:

https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/4379

paddddiinnnnngggg

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is that Node doesn't do any magic when converting from a Buffer to a string, whether it is `ascii` or `utf8`. Your `utf8` string is totally invalid `ascii`, so I guess ideally it would throw an error, but obviously it doesn't. I would not expect the `è\u0081µ` since that is invalid `ascii`.

You can see [in the Node source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_buffer.cc#L249), the code for converting from a buffer to a string are the `...slice` functions. The `ascii` and `utf8` functions are identical, leading to the behavior you are seeing. These constructors don't do anything fancy, they just take a sequence of bytes and convert it into a JS string, assuming that it is valid in that encoding.

The differences between the two encodings come from the AsciiWrite and Utf8Write functions in that file, which treat things differently.

For example:

```
new Buffer("聵", 'ascii') // <Buffer 75>
new Buffer("聵", 'utf8')  // <Buffer e8 81 b5>
```

As you saw from your tests, `binary` fits better with what you are looking for. `binary` goes through each individual byte in a buffer and returns a string where each code point has that byte value.

```
(new Buffer([0xe8, 0x81, 0xb5])).toString('binary').charCodeAt(0); // 0xe8
```

Comment: That makes sense.  If the file is valid ASCII, it can be read as if it was UTF-8.  Node just doesn't do any validation.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing exactly what language that is, I am guessing Japanese (correct me if I am wrong).  But I believe it is purely coincidental that the characters you supplied happen to fall in the ascii standard, [Japanese character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language_and_computers#Character_encodings)

> However, Shift JIS has the unfortunate property that it often breaks
> any parser (software that reads the coded text) that is not
> specifically designed to handle it. For example, a text search method
> can get false hits if it is not designed for Shift JIS. EUC, on the
> other hand, is handled much better by parsers that have been written
> for 7-bit ASCII (and thus EUC encodings are used on UNIX, where much
> of the file-handling code was historically only written for English
> encodings). But EUC is not backwards compatible with JIS X 0201, the
> first main Japanese encoding. Further complications arise because the
> original Internet e-mail standards only support 7-bit transfer
> protocols. Thus JIS encoding was developed for sending and receiving
> e-mails.
>
> In character set standards such as JIS, not all required characters
> are included, so gaiji (外字 "external characters") are sometimes used
> to supplement the character set. Gaiji may come in the form of
> external font packs, where normal characters have been replaced with
> new characters, or the new characters have been added to unused
> character positions. However, gaiji are not practical in Internet
> environments since the font set must be transferred with text to use
> the gaiji. As a result, such characters are written with similar or
> simpler characters in place, or the text may need to be written using
> a larger character set (such as Unicode) that supports the required
> character.

I would try with some more "exotic" characters, as your test will fail.

Comment: That doesn't answer why node decodes the file as utf8 while explicitly told to decode it as ascii.  The expected behavior is an error, as 0xe8 is outside ascii range.

Comment: @Deestan Where in your original question did you say anything about utf8?  Unless I am missing something and binary == utf8?

Comment: I've taken a random unicode char, I don't know the language. If I use another character, like Ж, this one is encoded with 2 bytes, but again if I do `d === "Ж"` with ascii encoding it prints true.

Comment: The file is in UTF8-encoding.  0xE881B5 is the UTF8-encoding of 聵, and is what is stored in the file.  Reading this as UTF8 should give "聵".  Reading it as binary should give "\u00e8\u0081\u00b5".  Reading it as ASCII should give an error.

Comment: @Deestan reading it in ascii wouldn't throw an error if node.js converts it like so `&#1046;`  and does some magic on the back end

Comment: If node ignores my encoding parameter and does "some magic" instead, then *yes* apparently it does not give an error as it should.

Comment: @Deestan I realize saying some magic is trite, but I don't have access to node.js here at work so I am trying to deduce things without knowledge.